# When do I have to call XInitThreads?

Tags: multithreading, xlib, glx

I understand that if there are two or more threads sharing a single X display connection, `XInitThreads` must be called before any other Xlib call.

But what if every thread has its own connection to the display and operates only on that connection? Is `XInitThreads` still necessary? And does it make difference if I use the GLX extension?

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation:

> It is only necessary to call this function if multiple threads might **use Xlib concurrently.**  If all calls to Xlib functions are protected by some other access mechanism (for example, a mutual exclusion lock in a toolkit or through explicit client programming), Xlib thread initialization is not required. It is recommended that single-threaded programs not call this function.

So, it seems that even if the threads use different connections, XInitThreads must be called.

I suggest you to call XInitThread just before you create your threads. This way everything should be OK.